# What kind of siding and install type is this?

Tags: siding

The siding looks like its not one flat piece but made of multiple flat layers? There are different siding installment methods. What does this one look like?

If I was going to search home depot for a similar arrangement/type of siding, what would I look for?
[image: My unknown siding]

Comment: Take photos with a tape measure for scale and go to a real lumberyard. The big box stores are a waste of time in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Your siding is shiplap, you can see that the grain pattern continues from the face of the board onto the lapped edge. Normally the boards are milled so that the faces fit close together, so it could be called "lap and gap" for clarity. I've no idea if that's a regional term or not.

If it had actually been made of two layers it would be board and batten, which may offer you some visually similar style products in your search. Traditionally though the batts are much smaller than the boards, and the siding is installed vertically to shed water.

Answer (score 2):

I would call that "shiplap" (but some will refer to it as tongue & groove), but names may differ based on location.

The idea of the joint is so that water does not stay on the joint between the two planks, but falls away.

Comment: Shiplap and tongue-and-groove are two distinct things. The former usually has just a rabbet on the back so it laps the board below while staying tight to the substrate (though it may have a shallow groove). The latter has a full groove.

Comment: @isherwood you need to listen to what some people ask for when they go into "B&Q" "Homebase" or "Homedepot" or equivalent - they have no idea what to ask for - surprisingly some can recognise the difference between painted wood and plastic, but not all...

Comment: @isherwood there are several types of tongue and groove - at least where I can go, some have chamfers on both sides, one side or none... The effort to answer a comment and it's gone...

Comment: Yes, I know this, but this particular siding is either grooved or its not. My point was that true shiplap is not also referred to as t&g (except by the ignorant). Nothing further from me.

Answer (score 2):

We have that on our house and around here it is called lap and gap. I have replaced some rotted courses and had to go to a lumberyard to get what I wanted. I have examined this type of siding in detail.

[cedar lap and gap siding](https://www.google.com/search?q=lap%20and%20gap%20cedar&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=wR3apotdVzfG0M%253A%252CyNshQAsKYaiCOM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQqvreKtn8pK_6ae8tT3LGOhXbbqA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpwJmtg_jiAhUHQq0KHTZYBBwQ9QEwAHoECAYQBA#imgrc=wR3apotdVzfG0M:)

Ship lap siding is installed without gaps, but there will be grooves. Lap and gap has a much longer lap on one end resulting in a distinctive wide horizontal gap. Some (lap and gap) siding can be installed with the rough side out to give lap and gap, but if installed with the smooth side out the result is no gap outside giving the effect of ship lap. However, there will be an internal gap. I would think that ship lap would have only a very narrow gap or no gap, just a groove.

Look at the design of the planks in the link.